# Street View setPosition Precision

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Can I control the precision of the setPosition function in Google Maps API?
I am using the following code to change the position of the streetview, in a business.

```
panorama.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(42.300735, -71.38617099999999));
panorama.setPov({ heading: 91.8, pitch: 0});
```

My project allows users to save a view.  Starting at position A, they can walk to different positions and it uses an eventListener and the getPosition function to save their new view, position B.  I have tested that it is returning unique values for each view.  When I try to jump to position B using this code, it goes back to position A, but uses position B's heading.  When I just initially load it with hard coded position B, it brings me to position A.

I think that this setPosition function isn't super precise, so when I use these slightly different lat-lng coordinates that are only 10 meters away from each other, it just brings me to the same panorama each time.  When I choose a position that is miles away, it works, but not for nearby positions.  Is there a way to control precision of this function?  My understanding of panoid is that it only persists through the browser session, so it would not be able to retrieve the saved view in a new session using panoid.

I also tried using the service to find nearby panos using getPanoramaByLocation with a radius of 20 meters, the only panorama it finds is position A, and of course if the position I want is more than 20 meters away I get no results.  But I do know there is a panorama there, because getPosition just gave it to me!  Very frustrating.  Anything that can be done?

here is a fiddle illustrating the issue http://jsfiddle.net/x5ewxn4t/
Clicking "Go to Back of Store" uses positionB but still finds positionA.

**EDIT**

This is just the way it is. The setPano function is how I ended up solving this, although it requires knowing the panoid, but allows you to jump straight to a pano. I ended up using setPano a lot when building this tour builder...
[pitchpeek.com](http://pitchpeek.com/) and I have a new version coming out soon.

Comment: I just reported it.  I think my code is so basic and it works when the locations are far apart...so the same code not working when the locations are close does seem like a bug.  I really thought I had seen this out there, but maybe nobody can do it right now?

Comment: There are several bug reports of this in the last 24 hours. Looks like it is a new issue, it happened once about a year ago also so there are related bugs already.  Good to know I'm not broken, Google is!

Comment: The described behavior is still the same. Setting the panoID directly doesn't result in a smooth transition animation but rather turns black and pops up at the new location.